# How can you open then close a Bootstrap modal with only html?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

You can use `class="modal show"` to open the modal, but it won't toggle close.  I am doing this only in html and need to limit the use of Javascript I use.  I am not sure if there is another command to do this in html?

```
  <?php
  $row="1";
  if(isset($_REQUEST['submitted'])) {

    $Page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $page = explode('?', $Page);

    if(isset($page[1])) {
        if(strpos($page[1], '&') != false) {
            $PAGE = explode('&', $page[1]);
            $searchString = $PAGE['1'];

            if($searchString == $row) {


                print "


                    <div class='modal show' style='z-index:10000' id=\"$row[auditID]\" role='dialog'>
                        <div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'>
                            <div class='modal-content'>
                                <div class='modal-header'>
                                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'></button>
                                <h4 class='modal-title'>Perform Audit</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class='modal-body' >

                                </div>
                                <div class='modal-footer'>

                                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>No</button>

                                    </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>

                ";
            }
        }   
    }

   }else {

   ?>

   <a href="?submitted=1&<?php print $row; ?>">Test</a>
   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Does `<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'></button>` not close the modal for you?

Comment: I just tried your solution but it won't close for some reason...  Must be something about hard coding in the show for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You should remove "show" class in your modal, add it an id like "myModal" and using default script from Bootstrap.

Your modal initializes and invokes show immediately

```js
$('#myModal').modal('show')
```

```css
<div class='modal' role='dialog' id="myModal">
....
</div>
```